# How to add an Item to scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am very new to Angular JS and mongod. I want to be able to push a new ingredient field into this page to the specific drink the the + button is on.

**This is my view**

[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vucJX.png)

**This is my .jade file** `block content
  div.container-fluid(ng-controller="DrinkController", ng-init="setDrinks( #{JSON.stringify(drinks)} )")
    div.row
      div.col-md-2
      div.col-md-8
        h1.title Edit Drinks
    div.row
      div.col-md-3 
        b Name
      div.col-md-3 
        b Filename
      div.col-md-1
      div.col-md-5 
        b Ingredients
    div.row.editRow(ng-repeat="drink in drinks | orderBy: 'name'")
      form(ng-submit="editDrink(drink)")
        div.col-md-3 
          input(value="{{drink.name}}", ng-model="drink.name")
        div.col-md-3
          input(value="{{drink.image}}", ng-model="drink.image")
        div.col-md-1.text-right 
          a(ng-click="addNewIngredientEd()") +
        div.col-md-4
          div.row(ng-repeat="ingredient in drink.ingredients")
            div.col-md-7
              select.mixers(value="{{ingredient.name}}", ng-model="ingredient.name", ng-options="i for i in ingredientsList")
            div.col-md-4
              input.addForm.ingredient(value="{{ingredient.amount}}", ng-model="ingredient.amount", style="width: 100px;")
            div.col-md-1 
              a(ng-click="removeIngredientEdit($index)") -
        div.col-md-1
          button.btn Save`

**This is my Related JS**

```
$scope.addNewIngredientEd = function () {
$scope.newDrink.ingredients.push({ name: '', amount: 0 });

//alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
console.log('Added new ingredient Test ');
};
```

Comment: Could you show more code? Is the controller being assigned in the html?

Comment: I added all of my .jade file

Comment: Are you sure to use `ng-init="setDrinks( #{JSON.stringify(drinks)}`  instead of `ng-init="setDrinks( #{JSON.parse(drinks)}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `$index`, it's part of ng-repeat

```
addNewIngredientEd($index)
```

and

```
$scope.addNewIngredientEd = function ($index) {
   $scope.drinks[$index].ingredients.push(...
```

Comment: When I change my $scope.newDrink.ingredients.push to $scope.drinks[$index].ingredients.push I get the error to the console saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ingredients' of undefined
    at Scope.DrinkController.$scope.addNewIngredientEd"